# "School of Applied Mathematics and Physical Sciences" en français (de ou des)

Tags: traduction, articles, absence-d-article, université

J'essaie de traduire en français le nom d'une École dont le nom en anglais est

> *School* of Applied Mathematics and Physical Sciences.

Je me demande quelle traduction, entre celles ci-après, est correcte:

> École des Mathématiques Appliquées et des Sciences Physiques.

ou

> École de Mathématiques Appliquées et Sciences Physiques.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*École **des** Mathématiques...* is almost never used despite *mathématiques* being a plural so I would suggest the second choice or :

> *(École de) Mathématiques appliquées et Physique-Chimie*

Comment: Donc, on ne peut pas besoin de répéter de ici, non ? (École de) Mathématiques appliquées et Physique-Chimie. Pourquoi alors on dit Attache temporaire d'enseignement et **de** recherche ? Ici, on répète **de**. (merci pour la réponse:-)!).

Comment: On est pas obligé de mettre le deuxième *de* mais on peut quand même le faire, sauf si bien sûr on retire *école de*.